# how to bind select option value in spring mvc

Tags: spring

I want to add value in database by select box option.and all is working good.but when i select value from the select box.selected value is added into database with new ID and skillCategory.
i never want to add it with new Id. so can someone tell me .what should i do 
my jsp code :

```
 <form:select id="skillCat" path="skillcategory.skillName">
  <c:forEach var="cate" items="${catagory}">
     <form:option value="${cate.skillcategoryId}">${cate.skillName}</form:option>
  </c:forEach>
 </form:select>
```

my controller code for skillCategory :

```
      private void prepareDataForWalkin(ModelMap map) {
    map.addAttribute("catagory", skillService.getSkillList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are indeed passing     ${cate.skillcategoryId} to skillcategory.skillName by doing

```
<form:option value="${cate.skillcategoryId}">${cate.skillName}</form:option>
```

If you want some other value instead of id to be passed, put that into to     <form:option>'s "value" attribute instead.

For example

```
<form:option value="${cate.skillName}">${cate.skillName}</form:option>
```

passes value of  ${cate.skillName} to your command variable skillcategory.skillName.